# Matching "short" name in "long" name

Tags: google-sheets, key, matching

In google sheet file I want to search for the presence of the short names (base, column B) within the long names (column D) and return the corresponding short name (example in column G)

I expect the formula will work like the results in "example" column G

Data set & example is below
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10qwohXEOzexyd5CGCTJpJeg01KpWrttRYvQWmozNpjo/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Λ,map(tocol(J4:J,1),lambda(Σ,index(trim(split(regexreplace(Σ,"\bfka\b|\bdba\b|Inc.|,",),"()"))))),
     map(L4:L,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,iferror(+tocol(index(if(len(Λ)*search(Λ,Σ),tocol(J4:J,1),)),3))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works almost perfectly for the first example, but almost doesn't work for the second example (I've added to the file) - could you please have a look?

Comment: Updated the formula but again as new data/scenarios come up I aint sure how robust its gonna be!